# Why does my last todo left do not get delete on first click in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am trying to fetch the data from the firebase and try to display it inside Todo component, the inputForm uses redux-form to handle validation. Once the form is submitted it calls the action creator which adds the data to firestore database and then list the todo items using the "listTodo" action creator, all of this request are asynchronous and uses redux-thunk as middleware, when i have list of todo items on screen and i try to delete the last todo item it do not get deleted on first click, but i have to click twice to delete the item. I am unable to solve this problem, anyone help me out with this problem.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <h1 className="text-center" style={{marginTop: "5vh"}}>Todo App</h1>
                <InputForm/>
                <Todo />
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

InputForm.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Col, Container, Form, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import {addTodo } from '../actions'



class InputForm extends React.Component {


    renderError = ({error, touched}) => {
        if(error && touched){
            return <p  style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</p>
        }
    }

    todoInput = ({input, meta}) => {
         return (
             <Form.Group>
             <Form.Control  {...input} />
             {this.renderError(meta)}
             </Form.Group>
         );
     };

     todoDate = ({input, meta}) => {
        return (    
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control type="date" {...input} />
                {this.renderError(meta)}
            </Form.Group>
        );
    };

    handleSubmit = (inputValues) => {
        this.props.addTodo(inputValues);
        inputValues.todo_input = null;
        inputValues.todo_date = null;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid  style={{marginTop: "12vh", marginBottom: "2.5%"}}>
                <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}> {/* just need to pass values to addtodo actions */}
                    <Row lg="auto" style={{marginLeft: "10%"}} >
                        <Col  md={6}>
                        <Field name="todo_input" component={this.todoInput} />
                        </Col><Col md="auto" >
                        <Field name="todo_date" component={this.todoDate} />
                        </Col><Col xs="auto" >
                            <Button type="submit" variant="success">Add Todo</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const validate = (inputValue) => {
    const errors = {};
    //error.something, here something must match the value of name of a Field component
    if(!inputValue.todo_input){
        //only ran if title is empty
        errors.todo_input  = "Please enter the todo";
    }
    if(!inputValue.todo_date){
        errors.todo_date ="Please enter the deadline"
    }

    return errors;
   
}



export default connect(null, {addTodo})(reduxForm({
    form: 'todo-input',
    validate
})(InputForm));
```

Todo.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {  Col, ListGroup, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import {deleteTodo} from '../actions'
import {listTodo} from '../actions'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class Todo extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.listTodo();
    }
    
    render(){
       
        if(this.props.list.length === 0){
            return (
                <ListGroup.Item className="w-50 mx-auto my-2" variant="success" style={{}}>
               <Row>
                    <h5 className="mx-auto text-center">Enter the todo item</h5>
               </Row>
                <Row>
                <p className="mx-auto">Deadline date will be mentioned here</p>
                </Row>
           </ListGroup.Item>
            )
        }
        if(this.props.list)
             //<div>Hello</div>
             return this.props.list.map(todo => {
                //console.log(todo);
                return (
                    <ListGroup key={todo.id}>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="w-50 mx-auto my-2" variant="success">
                            <Row>
                                    <Col xs={1}>
                                    <DeleteIcon onClick={() => this.props.deleteTodo(todo.id)}/>
                                    </Col><Col md={10}>
                                    <h5 className="text-center">{todo.todo.todo}</h5>
                                    </Col>
                            </Row>
                                <Row>
                                <p className="mx-auto">Deadline by {todo.todo.date}</p>
                                </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                )
            })
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     console.log(state.todoList);
     return  {
        list: state.todoList
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {deleteTodo, listTodo})(Todo)
```

actions/index.js

```
   import database from '../firebase/firebase'
export const addTodo = (inputValue) => async dispatch => {
    await database.collection('Todo').add({
        todo: inputValue.todo_input,
        date: inputValue.todo_date
        });
        sendTodo(dispatch);
}

export const listTodo = () => async dispatch=> {
    //console.log("Hi")
    sendTodo(dispatch);
}

export const deleteTodo = id => async dispatch => {
    //delete todo
    database.collection('Todo').doc(id).delete();
    sendTodo(dispatch);
}

const sendTodo = async (dispatch) => {
    let data = [];
    let todoRef = database.collection('Todo');
    let allTodos =  await todoRef.orderBy('todo').get();
    for(const doc of allTodos.docs){
        data.push({
            id: doc.id,
            todo: doc.data()
        }) 
    }
    //console.log(data);
     dispatch ({
         type: 'LIST_TODO',
         payload: data
     });
}
```

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form'
import todoReducer from './TodoReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
    todoList: todoReducer
});
```

Also, sometimes eventhough without submitting the form i got the error on my screen, can someone help me out in this!

Comment: your not updating todoList in the deleteTodo function and also use await with "database.collection('Todo').doc(id).delete()" and then update the todoList list

Answer (score 1):

I suspect database.collection('Todo').doc(id).delete() is probably asynchronous itself. Don't send your updated todos until it processes. (Put a .then on it and wait for it's then).. or await it.

Answer (score 1):

`.delete()` returns a promise. Use await inside an async function.

```
export const deleteTodo = id => async dispatch => {
    //delete todo
    async database.collection('Todo').doc(id).delete();
    sendTodo(dispatch);
}
```